# How to Combine find and grep for a complex search? ( GNU/linux, find, grep )

Tags: linux, command-line, find, grep, gnu

I'm trying to do a text search in some files that share a similar directory structure, but are not in the same directory tree, in GNU/Linux.

I have a web server with many sites that share the same tree structure (Code Igniter MVC PHP framework), so I want to search in a specific directory down the tree for each site, example:

`/srv/www/*/htdocs/system/application/`

Where * is the site name. And from those *application* directories, I want to search all the tree down to its leaves, for an *.php file that has some text pattern inside, let's say "debug(", no regular expression needed.

I know how to use *find* and *grep* but I'm not good at combining them.

How would I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

```
find /srv/www/*/htdocs/system/application/ -name "*.php" -exec grep "debug (" {} \; -print
```

This should recursively search the folders under `application` for files with `.php` extension and pass them to `grep`.

An optimization on this would be to execute:

```
find /srv/www/*/htdocs/system/application/ -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H "debug ("
```

This uses `xargs` to pass all the `.php` files output by `find` as arguments to a single `grep` command;
e.g., `grep "debug (" file1 file2 file3`. The `-print0` option of `find` and `-0` option of `xargs` ensure the spaces in file and directory names are correctly handled. The `-H` option passed to `grep` ensures that the filename is printed in all situations. (By default, `grep` prints the filename only when multiple arguments are passed in.)

From man xargs:

> `-0`
>
>     Input items are terminated by a null character instead of by whitespace, and the quotes and  backslash
>                     are  not  special  (every  character  is  taken literally).  Disables the end of file string, which is
>                     treated like any other argument.  Useful when input items might contain white space, quote  marks,  or
>                     backslashes.  The GNU find
>     `-print0`
>     option produces input suitable for this mode.

Comment: +1. That will execute grep for each php file, though. If there are lots of files, you can optimize further by `find /srv/www/*/htdocs/system/application/ -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "debug ("`

Comment: @jackem Agreed. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Another small improvement: xargs may just pass one filename to grep, in which case grep won't show the filename if there's a match.  You may want to add -H to the grep command to force it to show the filename.

Comment: @Randy That's a very valid point.

Comment: This is true necromancy, but `GNU find` can take the `+` operator instead of `\;` to perform the same sort of single process execution that `xargs` do. Thus, `find /srv/www/*/htdocs/system/application/ -name "*.php" -exec grep -H "debug (" {} +` does the same thing as the `xargs` example in this answer, but with one less process fork (and still 0 risk for file name troubles).

Answer (score 13):

`find` is not even needed for this example, one can use `grep` directly (at least `GNU grep`):

```
grep -RH --include='*.php' "debug (" /srv/www/*/htdocs/system/application/
```

and we are down to a single process fork.

Options:

- `-R, --dereference-recursive    Read all files under each directory, recursively. Follow all symbolic links, unlike -r.`
- `-H, --with-filename    Print the file name for each match. This is the default when there is more than one file to search.`
- `--include=GLOB    Search only files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard matching as described under --exclude).`
- `--exclude=GLOB    Skip any command-line file with a name suffix that matches the pattern GLOB, using wildcard matching; a name suffix is either the whole name, or any suffix starting after a / and before a +non-/. When searching recursively, skip any subfile whose base name matches GLOB; the base name is the part after the last /. A pattern can use *, ?, and [...] as wildcards, and \ to  quote a wildcard or backslash character literally.`

Comment: Just for curiosity, what do the `-RH` options mean?

Comment: @Gus: Added `man grep` excerpt of option descriptions to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell can find the php files and give them to grep. In bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob globstar
grep searchterm /srv/www/*/htdocs/system/application/**/*.php
```