# How do I find files containing two strings together in Linux?

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Combine find and grep for a complex search? ( GNU/linux, find, grep )](https://superuser.com/questions/46199/how-to-combine-find-and-grep-for-a-complex-search-gnu-linux-find-grep)

I have a file containing a text:

```
PADLST20120907:D:05B:UN:IBTA+TK4 17 JFL01+01'BGM+250+C'RFF+TN:TK4
```

I want to find this file in Linux, using these two strings: "JFL" and "20120907". As you see above, the file contains both "JFL" and "20120907". What should I write in command line? Stirngs may or may not be in the same line.

I want to see file names with full path in the output. I don't want to see error messages or permission denied warnings. I want to search recursively in the directory I am standing in or I would like to specifiy a path.

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple bash loop will do what you need:

```
$ grep -rl JFL . | while read n; do grep -l 20120907 $n; done
```

If your file names contain spaces, do:

```
$ grep -rl JFL . | while read n; do grep -l 20120907 "$n"; done
```

To suppress error messages, redirect [standard error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) :

```
$ grep -rl JFL . 2>/de/null | while read n; do grep -l 20120907 "$n"; done
```